# Temporarily Disabling Django Caching

Tags: python, django

How do you disable Django caching on a per checkout basis?

Back before Django 1.3, I could disable caching for my local development checkout by specifying `CACHE_BACKEND = None`, in a settings_local.py imported by settings.py. The settings_local.py was ignored by SVN, so I could always ensure my local environment didn't cache, while not have to worry about modifying the cache params in settings.py.

Now, with Django 1.3, and the new CACHES = {...} structure, setting `CACHES = None` or `CACHES['default']['BACKEND'] = None` causes Django to choke, and setting `CACHES = {}` still seems to enable basic caching.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

[Dummy Caching (for development)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development) - this implements the cache interface, but doesn't actually cache so you could have it on your development/testing site to reduce caching and also prevent errors from caching, if those should arise.

> Finally, Django comes with a "dummy" cache that doesn't actually cache – it just implements the cache interface without doing anything.
>
> This is useful if you have a production site that uses heavy-duty caching in various places but a development/test environment where you don’t want to cache and don’t want to have to change your code to special-case the latter. To activate dummy caching, set BACKEND like so:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

Comment: New link is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development

Comment: Would dummy cache be used to not cause caching errors when working in development?

Comment: @MareksNo, yes, you could use DummyCache to avoid caching errors in your dev env, or even during initial testing in your CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: I don't want to set DummyCache for the whole `default` cache.
I would like to still be able to test the caching even when I disable Django template caching (to be able to see changes in the templates).

Answer (score 14):

I use this in my settings, so it's a bit more flexible i case I do want to test the usage of the deployed caching (in this case memcache)

```
TEST_MEMCACHE = False
if not DEBUG or TEST_MEMCACHE:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        }
    }
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Whilst using DRF, on some views, I would enable caching using `django.views.decorators.cache.cache_page`. The accepted answer did not work for me and I resorted to clearing the cache on tear down

```py
from django.core.cache import cache
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class SomeTestCase(APITestCase):

    def tearDown(self):
        cache.clear()
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution for multiple caches, and you want to disable all of them:

```
if True:
    CACHES = {
        k : {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',}
        for k in CACHES.keys()
    }
```

Solution if you want to disable some caches, may help:

```
if True:
    disable_names = [ 'cache_name' ]
    for name in disable_names:
        CACHES[name] = {'BACKEND' : 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',}
```

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose you can use "dummy" cache backend. Django comes with a "dummy" cache that doesn't actually cache -- it just implements the cache interface without doing anything.

Here are the [old style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#dummy-caching-for-development) and [new style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#dummy-caching-for-development) configuration formats.

1. old style

   To activate dummy caching, set CACHE_BACKEND like so:

   `CACHE_BACKEND = 'dummy://'`
2. new style

   ```
   CACHES = {
       'default': {
           'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
       }
   }
   ```