# django completely disable cache for good

Tags: django, apache, caching, mod-wsgi

I understand that django cache issues have been discussed heavily all over the web (e.g., [Temporarily Disabling Django Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602904/temporarily-disabling-django-caching)). But, this cache is driving me crazy.

I did disable the cache from the settings and used @never_cache for my views. I'm doing micro unit tests and I want to test every line of code. Unfortunately, django keeps on showing the old page for a few minutes before it refreshes it.

My setting: django on Apache's mod_wsgi

Even with a simple view with one line of text in it, this problem persists.

Question: Can django's cache be entirely disabled for good? I cannot do any debugging/testing while even minimum caching is there.

Comment: This has *nothing whatsoever* to do with caching, but with how Apache runs wsgi processes. However, I don't understand what "micro unit tests" are or why you would be running any kind of unit tests against an actual real server.

Comment: Can you expand on how you're running your tests. Daniel is very likely correct that the caching you're seeing is just due to mod_wsgi. That said, using apache + mod_wsgi can be overkill (http://youtu.be/voq4Mm58NY0?t=29m35s), and you might have an easier time with something like uwsgi / gunicorn.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, that was my issue. I had to run it on Apache at the time. Now it's fixed. Thanks.